# where is container View in collectionViewCell.xib

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, xib

There is a contentView in UITableViewCell's .xib file

[image]

But there isn't a contentView in UICollectionViewCell's .xib file

[image]

but in corresponding .swift file there exist a property called contentView

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why?